# phantom command not working in beamer poster template

Tags: spacing, beamerposter

I am using the Jacobs Landscape beamer poster template, and want to simply add a little phantom space at the beginning of a line within a block, but whatever I have inside the {} prints. The block is in a nested column, but the text is not within an example or any other unusual formatting. What could the problem be here? I am typesetting using xelatex because I am using packages that do not work with pdflatex.

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal, yet *complete* document illustrating the problem and a link to the template you are using, in case it's not on CTAN.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Some horizontal space commands don't work at the beginning of a line.  One can generally fix this by starting the line with things like \noindent, \strut, \null or {}.